# Outlook 2007 wont let me add RSS feeds

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, rss

I have Outlook 2007, but I'm having trouble adding RSS feeds. When I go 'Tools -> Account Settings...', I have no RSS Feeds tab (that should apparently be there), and when I right click the RSS Feeds folder, the options for 'Add a New RSS Feed' and 'Import an OPML File...' are both grayed out.

I have found a [post on here](https://superuser.com/questions/30028/rss-tab-not-shown-in-outlook-2007) that suggested an option was long ago clicked to remove RSS feeds, but I honestly don't know if that is the case. The post suggested removing a registry key to re-enable all RSS features, but said key does not exist.

Does anybody know what is going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Are using Outlook on a network at your work? If so, this could be a restriction put in place by the network administrator. If the registry key in not there, my guess is there is a policy disabling it.

Comment: @CharlieRB - Good call, it was an ancient GPO that disabled RSS features in Outlook. Changed the GPO yesterday, and all is fine at when logging on today. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I will place my answer below so you can choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Outlook on a network at your work, there could be a restriction put in place by the network administrator. If the registry key in not there, it is likely there is a policy disabling RSS.